# What does `tfms_from_model()` exactly do?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, fast-ai

I've been trying to follow a code which uses `fastai v0.7.0` with the `conv_learner` methods. There's a piece where the author uses `tfms_from_model()` for transforming inputs.
My question here is, what exactly does `tfms_from_model()` produce?

```
model = vgg16(pre=True).cuda().eval()
set_trainable(model, False)

sz = 224
train_tfms, val_tfms = tfms_from_model(vgg16, sz)
```

I'm asking the question because I can't use `fastai 0.7.0` because there's no pytorch support for it anymore. So I'm just guessing and manually implementing the things that `tfms_from_model()` does. Here's the implementation I found

```
picture = PIL.Image.open("test/206px-Wattledcranethumb.jpg")
plt.imshow(picture)
```

[image]

```
transformed = val_tfms(np.array(picture)/255)
plt.imshow(transformed.transpose(1,2,0))
```

[image]

So what exactly is val_tfms doing? Is it just normalizing images for the model as per the model's expected inputs? (For e.g. VGG16 requires channel wise mean being subtracted from it and then dividing by the sd for it's normalization)

What would happen if I put something like this?

```
sz = 56
train_tfms, val_tfms = tfms_from_model(vgg16, sz)
```

Is this also equivalent to doing this:

```
def normalize(x):
    # Some arbitrary normalization
    return normalized_x

picture = normalize(picture)
picture = torch.tensor(picture)
```

Comment: Are you using fast-ai v0.7.0?

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm trying to translate the code from fast-ai v0.7.0 in such a way that I don't have to use fast-ai. I want to be able to use pure pytorch for performing all the operations that fast-ai is performing.

Comment: My question is actually, is this code fast-ai v0.7, I'm asking because the official for it isn't available anymore and this function in particular has been removed in the new released version.

Comment: Yes, the code uses fast-ai v0.7

Comment: You might want to look into [here](https://github.com/Gokkulnath/fastai-v0.7/blob/19731a1a85305d201eedc214fb42db13b9e353af/fastai/transforms.py#L724) which is an unofficial repository dump of fast-ai v0.7.